# Android - OnTouchListener not firing if already pressing screen

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I have a RelativeLayout with a single ImageView inside of it. The ImageView has an OnTouchListener attached to it which is working perfectly fine if I just press the ImageView. The problem I'm having though is that if I press and hold in the empty space outside of the ImageView and *then* try to press the ImageView the touch listener doesn't fire. It seems like the layout is absorbing the touch events somehow. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The action defined by you here is a `Multi-touch gesture`. Go through [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) doc to know how to handle this type of actions.

Also take a look at the [ACTION_POINTER_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) action define in `MotionEvent`. This is the event that will get called when additional fingers come down.

Answer (score 0):

you mout use this code:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //your code
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //your code
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //your code
                    break;

                default:
                    //your code
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```